# jQuery Supersized IE9 issue

Tags: jquery, windows, background, internet-explorer-9, supersized

So as you can see in this image http://cl.ly/image/3I0K1c1J3L1T for some reason IE9 is not scaling the Supersized slideshow as it is in every other browser. Just to show it is working in other IE browsers I placed IE8 right next to it.

After doing some research I removed this from my "head"

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"
```

But without any luck. Any ideas?

You can check out the code on [this page](http://comanchenationcasinos.com.s163905.gridserver.com/) if you'd like.

I'm running Windows on a separate laptop for testing, but it's Windows 8 so it won't run IE9 separately or in IE Tester for some reason.

Comment: Don't know if they're related to this, but make sure you don't have anything (including whitespace) before the doctype declaration. Browsers can be finicky about stuff before that. Also, you shouldn't need the HTML5 shim for IE9, so you can change your conditional comment from `lte IE 9` to `lt IE 9`.

Comment: Tried that with no luck. :( Might have to wait til I get the chance to go home and see it on IE9 live.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm having the same issue on IE11 although I can't reproduce it consistently.